# How do I place resources inside the .EXE?

Tags: .net, localization

The "standard" way to have language specific resources in .NET is to have a folder under the .EXE for each language and then in the folder have a file filename.resources.dll. This leads to a lot of folders all over the place under every directory we have an .EXE in that has been localized.

Is there a way to place these resources inside the .EXE?

thanks - dave

Comment: An obvious workaround is to put all of .exe files in the same directory.  Why do you worrywart about this?  The file system driver doesn't.

Comment: @Hans Passant - we've had complaints from users about when they go to the bin directory they ask "what's with the ton of subfolders in there." Just trying to make it easier for people to find stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're not happy with your app being monolingual (in which case you can embed resources in your assembly).

The localization model provided by the .NET Framework depends on the file structure you describe. So to answer your question, you can't. Of course you can keep all assemblies in one folder, which means you'll only have one language subfolder per language.

You could try and build a custom Resource Manager and use resources embedded together in your assemblies, but I think it would complicate your process a lot (for example you'd have to rebuild and redeploy everything if you add a language or change one translation, and managing translations would be a real pain if everything is merged together).

Comment: Not the answer I wanted but if it has to be this way then I know not to hit my head against a wall trying for a better solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add resources from within the project *properties*. Just right click on the project and choose *properties*. Then select the *resources* options and add the resources that you need to be embedded into the assembly.

[MSDN for more...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I can add my own resources that way. But I want to add language specific resources to Control properties. For example, the Text property. If I use the language specific method in Visual Studio, it then uses the property value based on the locale the app is running in.